# Machine learning ensamble over ensamble results. Is this valid?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning

I have a dataset for which I run multiple algorithms over different subsets of its columns, but at the end, I want to classify each row (In my example, the data is the number, and the classification is "odd"/"even". 
I have the results from those many algorithms; as expected, some perform better than others in some cases, and vice versa. 
So.. I want to ensamble their results... for that, I can simply run a majority voting over the results; if 2 of 3 say it´s even and one says it´s odd, I´ll classify as even. 
BUT... I can also run a algorithms over those classifications (a KNN and a Naive Bayes in my example columns). (Is that ok?)

And then, I can vote over the classification made over the "classification dataset" - columns G,H,I, and decide again.

I have many doubts about this: 
Is this a good approach? Why? Why not? 
How should I divide my data and how should I validate the results?

Model:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use different classifiers applied to the entire dataset and all classes (for each classifier).  The result of using each classifier can merely be accuracy (which applies to all the classes) -- that is, what per cent of objects were assigned to their true class?   The trick for the ensemble is to take each test object $\bf x$ and assign it to the majority class that each classifier assigned it to.  (each classifier votes for each test object, so whichever predicted class is most frequent for the test object, that's the class that object is assigned to).

Comment: I applied different classifiers to the entire dataset (or just some columns of it for some, as some didn´t admit text). 
Then, I got the classification given by each. Then, can I take the columns D,E,F and run new algorithms over that? See G,H,I. And then, vote over those columns?
I have 2 "layers" now. The classification over the original data, and then the classification over the classifications. 
Is that a good and/or common practice? How should I design this thinking about training/testing/validation?

Comment: I wouldn't use algorithms that makes class predictions and then use classifiers of those classifications.   I would use all five of your classifiers and majority voting among the 5.  (don't majority vote with A1,A2,A3 separately and then majority vote with kNN and NBC separately). Instead majority vote from A1,A2,A3, kNN,NBC once for each test object.

Comment: why wouldn´t you? That´s my main question. Thanks!